# Add form values dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript code to dynamically add values on a form as they're entered. However, I'm struggling a little with what I want to do.

I have 4 questions on a quiz, each with 4 answers.

I want to add the values for each of the 4 answer boxes per question. But I can't work out how to use this script more than once on a page. Can anyone advise please?

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function updatesum1() {
            document.form.sum.value = (document.form.sum1.value - 0)
                                    + (document.form.sum2.value - 0)
                                    + (document.form.sum3.value - 0)
                                    + (document.form.sum4.value - 0);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form" >
            Enter a number:
            <input name="sum1" onChange="updatesum1()" />
            and another number:
            <input name="sum2" onChange="updatesum1()" />
            and another number:
            <input name="sum3" onChange="updatesum1()" />
            and another number:
            <input name="sum4" onChange="updatesum1()" />
            Their sum is:
            <input name="sum" readonly style="border:0px;">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: Where's the PHP?

Comment: The php comes after submitting - I want to get this to add before submit. Not got that far yet as I can't get this to work more than once per page :-(

Comment: @Neil add the full code, PHP as well, can't help if there's no context

Comment: Press F12 to bring up the developer tools in your browser and see if there's an error message in the Javascript console.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the form as an argument to the function, instead of hard-coding it in the function. In the input elements, `this.form` refers the form that contains it.

```js
function updatesum1(form) {
  form.sum.value = (form.sum1.value - 0) +
    (form.sum2.value - 0) +
    (form.sum3.value - 0) +
    (form.sum4.value - 0);
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
  Enter a number:
  <input name="sum1" onChange="updatesum1(this.form)" /> <br>
  and another number:
  <input name="sum2" onChange="updatesum1(this.form)" /> <br>
  and another number:
  <input name="sum3" onChange="updatesum1(this.form)" /> <br>
  and another number:
  <input name="sum4" onChange="updatesum1(this.form)" /> <br>
  Their sum is:
  <input name="sum" readonly style="border:0px;">
</form>
<p>
<form name="form">
  Enter a number:
  <input name="sum1" onChange="updatesum1(this.form)" /> <br>
  and another number:
  <input name="sum2" onChange="updatesum1(this.form)" /> <br>
  and another number:
  <input name="sum3" onChange="updatesum1(this.form)" /> <br>
  and another number:
  <input name="sum4" onChange="updatesum1(this.form)" /> <br>
  Their sum is:
  <input name="sum" readonly style="border:0px;">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how I would have done it, but it changes the "sum" as you want it to in chrome.

If you are able to use jQuery I would head that route.

> 

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".addInput").on("change", function () {//jQuery's on event handles all inputs

                updateSum();//call the function
            });

            function updateSum() {//This function could be made more generic.

               var sum1 = parseInt($("#sum1").val());
               var sum2 = parseInt($("#sum2").val());
               var sum3 = parseInt($("#sum3").val());
               var sum4 = parseInt($("#sum4").val());

               if(isNaN(sum1)){//make sure the input contains a parsable number.
                   sum1 = 0;
               }
               if(isNaN(sum2)){
                   sum2 = 0;
               }
               if(isNaN(sum3)){
                   sum3 = 0;
               }
               if(isNaN(sum4)){
                   sum4 = 0;
               }

               var sum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4;//add everything up


                $("#sum").val(sum);//add it to te sum input
            }
        });

        //function updatesum1() {
        //    document.form.sum.value = (document.form.sum1.value - 0)
        //                            + (document.form.sum2.value - 0)
        //                            + (document.form.sum3.value - 0)
        //                            + (document.form.sum4.value - 0);
        //}
    </script>
    <title>Input Adding</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form" >
        Enter a number:
        <input name="sum1" class="addInput" id="sum1" value/>
        and another number:
        <input name="sum2" class="addInput" id="sum2" value/>
        and another number:
        <input name="sum3" class="addInput" id="sum3" value/>
        and another number:
        <input name="sum4" class="addInput" id="sum4" value/>
        Their sum is:
        <input name="sum" id="sum" readonly style="border:0px;">
    </form>       

</body>
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: Thank you, all, really helpful!